# expand particular node in dojo tree

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I have three nodes in the tree and would like to keep the first node expanded, is there a way in dojo tree which would support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have id of the node that you want to expand. you can expand that node as follows - 
myTree will be your tree and expandNodeId is the id of the node you want to expand.

```
var nodes = myTree.getNodesByItem(expandNodeId);

if(!nodes[0].isExpanded){
     myTree._expandNode(nodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: What is "expandedNodeId" supposed to be?  Is it branch node or leaf node?

Comment: It is id of the node's data item. tree example here -https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree.html has a node named "The earth", id for that node is "world".

Answer (score 0):

In the above case the expandNodeId is the ID that you assigned to the node that was clicked. So, in your onClick() function you can do something like this;

```
            var theTree = new Tree({
                model: myModel,
                onClick: function(item, node){

                    // auto-expand the node when clicked
                    var nodes = that.theTree.getNodesByItem(item.id);
                    if(!nodes[0].isExpanded)
                        theTree._expandNode(nodes[0]);

                }
            });
```